# Update Record - Ruby On Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm newbie on ruby on rails. I have a User model with those attributes : login, email, role and group.

Here my file /app/models/user.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  login      :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  role       :integer
#  group      :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :login, :email, :role, :group

        def self.search(search)
        if search
            where('login LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
            else
            scoped
        end
    end
end
```

Here my app/views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :login %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :login, :readonly => true%>
    </br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:role, Role.all, :id, :name)
 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I click on Update button, I go to the User show page. 
I've got this trace :

```
Started PUT "/users/4"
  processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HBB9IcKpWyjSbrmh6os=", "user"=>{"role"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"4"}
Redirected to http%3A%2F%2F10.100.2.66%3A3000%2Fusers%2F4
Completed 302 Found in 1ms
```

Here my app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :require_admin
     helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction


  def new
    @title = "Sign up"
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = "User"

  end

  def edit
    @title = "Edit User"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10)

  end

  def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])

     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
        redirect_to @user
     else
        @title = "Edit user"
        render 'edit'
     end

  end

  def get
    @user = User.find(params[:login])
  end
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. If in index, I force the update of a user like that, it's working :

```
def index
  @testUser = User.find(6)
  @test.user.update_attributes(:role => "2")
  ...
end
```

It's like the instructions in update aren't executed. If i do :

```
def update
  logger.info("i am in update)
   ...
end
```

I don't have any log

here the result of rake routes command :

I hope I was clear. Sorry for my english, he is very bad.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: My problem is i can't update my user record.

Answer (score 0):

The logs indicate that it is indeed reaching the update action:

```
Started PUT "/users/4"
  processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HBB9IcKpWyjSbrmh6os=", "user"=>{"role"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"4"}
Redirected to http://10.100.2.66:3000/users/4
Completed 302 Found in 1ms
```

The first line looks like the show action, but remember show actions are GET requests. Being a "PUT" request means it's routed to the update action. Running `rake routes` confirms this:

```
rake routes
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)    {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
```

This is further confirmed by line 2: `processing by UsersController#update as HTML` tells us rails is processing the update action of UsersController as HTML (as opposed to JSON for example).

On another topic, I noticed your `User#role` attribute is misleading. You should name it `role_id` to indicate it's an integer associated with `Role`, and update your code like this:

```
# user.rb
attr_accessible :role_id
belongs_to :role

# app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= f.collection_select(:role_id, Role.all, :id, :name)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer and your help. I've changed the User#role attribute to User#role_id. But for the main topic, for you, everything seem ok ? Do I have to post more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of wrong variable:

```
def index
  @testUser = User.find(6)
  @test.user.update_attributes(:role => "2")
  ...
end
```

it must be:

```
def index
  @testUser = User.find(6)
  @testUser.update_attributes(:role => "2")
  ...
end
```

Or maybe you can you this:

```
@testUser = User.find(6)
@testUser.role = 2
@testUser.save
```